# How to run a react app without using node?

Tags: reactjs

I want to run react from the HTML page so that it is displayed on the browser. Till now I was using node to run it but now I want that when I open my HTML file in the browser my react app should run there.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html

Answer (score 2):

A production build might be what you need. Try executing `npm run build` (or `yarn build`, if you're using Yarn).

This creates a production build of your app in the `build` folder, which contains `index.html` along with other static files. Running `index.html` should run the app in your browser.

A production build is meant to be served to the end user, so remember that you won't be getting any nice crash messages or stack traces that you get from running it on Node. Neither would development-related niceties like hot-reloading work. If you're still working on your project actively, keep using Node.

By the way, if you just need to make any changes to the HTML file of your React app (like changing the title or adding an external script), you can do that in `public/index.html` too - you don't need to create a production build for that.